# How can I prove that the conditional entropy of $X$ given $Y$ is $0$ if and only if $Y = f(X)$?

Tags: conditional-probability, entropy, information-theory

I want to show that:

$$
H(X|Y) = 0 \iff Y=f(X)
$$

Where $H(X|Y)$ is the average conditional entropy of the discrete random variable $X$ over all values of the discrete random variable $Y$, and $f$ is an arbitrary invertible function. $H(X|Y)$ is defined as:

$$
H(X|Y) = \mathbb{E}_{p(y)} [H(X|Y=y)] = \sum_y p(y) H(X|Y=y)
$$

$H(X|Y=y)$ is the conditional entropy of the discrete random variable $X$ given $Y = y$:

$$
H(X|Y=y) = \mathbb{E}_{p(x|y)} [-\log_2{p(x|y)}] = - \sum_x p(x|y) \log_2 (p(x|y))
$$

So:

$$ \begin{align}
H(X|Y) &= - \sum_y p(y) \sum_x p(x|y) \log_2 (p(x|y)) \\
&= - \sum_y \sum_x p(x,y) \log_2 (p(x|y)) \\
&= - \mathbb{E}_{p(x,y)} [\log_2 (p(x|y))]
\end{align}$$

I am aware of these questions and their answers:

- [Conditional Entropy: if $H[y|x]=0$, then there exists a function $g$
  such that $y=g(x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3383199/conditional-entropy-if-hyx-0-then-there-exists-a-function-g-such-that)
- [when it is conditional entropy minimized?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/848158/when-it-is-conditional-entropy-minimized)
- [Zero conditional entropy](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1404725/zero-conditional-entropy)

However, none of them offer a satisfactory and straightforward answer.

---

It turns out that problem 2.5 in the 2nd edition of the book *Elements of Information Theory* by Cover & Thomas addresses this problem, although using different wording. Problem 2.5 states:

> *Zero conditional entropy*. Show that if $H(Y|X)=0$, then $Y$ is a function of $X$ [i.e., for all $x$ with $p(x)>0$, there is only one possible value of $y$ with $p(x,y)>0$]

This is actually how I intended to word my question. I've checked the solutions manual for the solution to this problem, but I don't fully understand the proof and would appreciate a bit of explanation. Here is the solution verbatim:

Assume that there exists an $x$, say $x_0$ and two different values of $y$, say $y_1$ and $y_2$ such that $p(x_0,y_1)>0$ and $p(x_0,y_2)>0$. Then $p(x_0) \geq p(x_0,y_1) + p(x_0,y_2) > 0$, and $p(y_1|x_0)$ and $p(y_2|x_0)$ are not equal to $0$ or $1$. Thus

$$ \begin{align}
H(Y|X) &= -\sum_x p(x) \sum_y p(y|x) \log p(y|x) \\
& \geq p(x_0)(-p(y_1|x_0) \log p(y_1|x_0) - p(y_2|x_0) \log p(y_2|x_0)) \\
& > 0,
\end{align}$$

since $-t \log t \geq 0$ for $0 \leq t \leq 1$, and is strictly positive for $t$ not equal to $0$ or $1$. Therefore the conditional entropy $H(Y|X)$ is $0$ if and only if $Y$ is a function of $X$.

Comment: The title doesn't exactly match with your question in the beginning. Also, what happens when $f(x)$ is a constant function?

Comment: @gunes you are correct. Fixed the title. I am not sure what happens when $f(x)$ is a constant function. I know that the statement is true, but don't know how to prove it.

Comment: There must be conditions on f, like one to one.

Comment: @gunes good point. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_entropy#Conditional_entropy_equals_zero) is not clear about this either. I have checked other sources, but all of them have the statement as *$Y$ is completely determined by $X$*.

Comment: For the sake of clarity, let us assume that $f$ is invertible. Edited the post to reflect this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can't be proved because it's not true. Here are a couple counterexamples.

Suppose $p(x,y) = p(x) p(y)$ and $p(x)$ is a delta function, so $X$ always takes a constant value. This implies that $H(X \mid Y) = 0$. However, if $p(y)$ is anything other than a delta function, $Y$ cannot be a deterministic function of $X$. Therefore:

$$H(X \mid Y) = 0 \enspace {\not\!\!\!\implies} Y = f(X)$$

Conversely, consider a case where $Y=f(X)$ and $f$ is noninvertible over the support of $p(x)$ (e.g. $p(x)$ could be uniform and $f$ could be a constant function). That is, we have a non-zero probability of drawing multiple values of $X$ that are mapped to the same value of $Y$. This implies that $H(X \mid Y) \ne 0$. Therefore:

$$Y = f(X) \enspace {\not\!\!\!\implies} H(X \mid Y) = 0$$

Comment: I wrote this before the question was edited to restrict $f$ to be invertible. So, the second counterexample no longer applies, but the first still stands.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I actually found another answer from a textbook, and I have edited my question to include this answer. However, the answer is not straightforward. What do you think?

Comment: @mhdadk The excerpt from Cover&Thomas doesn't answer your question because it's talking about $H(Y \mid X)$, whereas you asked about $H(X \mid Y)$. Please take a look at the answer I posted; it directly addresses your question and shows that the statement cannot be true.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you some hints.

The fact $p(x_0) = \sum_yp(x_0,y)$ gives you the bound on $p(x_0)$.

The fact $-t\log t \geq 0$ for $0 < t <1$ allows you to say that the sum over all $x,y$ is bigger than the sum over only $x_0,y_1, y_2$ as you're summing positive quantities.

Then you're multiplying 2 strictly positive quantities, so it's bigger than $0$.

But you assumed it **was** zero, contradiction! CQFD.